# Why two items in the same relative layout are differently layouted?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a listview with item specified by RelativeLayout

There is an image (gray arrow, this is png, with transparent padding). In first case text with blue back overlaps this image, in second - it is aligned.
The only difference between these cases is that left photo is invisible in first case. I do not understand why in second case the blue text does not overlap gray arrow? (it is desirable behavior)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_content">
  <ru.ip_news.ui.views.RationalImage
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/article_short_image_width"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
  <View
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/padding_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/picture"/>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dis_ind"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dis_ind"/>   
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/separator"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dis_ind"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/article_text_main"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:background="#F0F0"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/separator"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="@color/article_text_secondary"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:background="#F00F"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with Android coding before, but just from looking at your code I'd say there's a conflict between `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` found here:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dis_ind"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dis_ind"/>
```

and your `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` found here:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/separator"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="@color/article_text_secondary"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:background="#F00F"/>
```

I've never worked with the code base before and don't have a "solution" for you, but maybe it'll get you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Since the picture no longer exists in the top view , the layout has become smaller so the textviews are closer. Put some margin between the two text views to fix the issue.

Comment: Note that first case is desirable. So adding margin will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem by extracting linearlayout and moving photo to it. For some reason this photo in the same layout involves space between texts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_content">
    <ru.ip_news.ui.views.RationalImage
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/article_short_image_width"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <RelativeLayout   
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_content">
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dis_ind"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dis_ind"/>   
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dis_ind"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/article_text_main"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@color/article_text_secondary"
        android:maxLines="4"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```